# Как удалить столбцы с определенным количество пропусков в DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, nan

Есть следующий датасет:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
7   9   9   7       4
6   7   3   5   9   10
6   5   4   3       2
8   3   9   6   4   8
6   10  6   8       5
10      5   2   7   5
4           4   4   7
4           4   8   10
10  5   4   3   7   10
5   8   4   4   6   7
```

Необходимо оставить только те столбцы, в которых % пропусков (NaN) не превышает 20%.
Соответственно необходимо получить следующее:

```
Col1    Col3    Col4    Col6
7   9   7   4
6   3   5   10
6   4   3   2
8   9   6   8
6   6   8   5
10  5   2   5
4       4   7
4       4   10
10  4   3   10
5   4   4   7
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.dropna(..., threshold=<>)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
res = df.dropna(thresh=int(len(df) * .8), axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [55]: res
Out[55]:
   Col1  Col3  Col4  Col6
0     7   9.0     7     4
1     6   3.0     5    10
2     6   4.0     3     2
3     8   9.0     6     8
4     6   6.0     8     5
5    10   5.0     2     5
6     4   NaN     4     7
7     4   NaN     4    10
8    10   4.0     3    10
9     5   4.0     4     7
```

**NOTE:** учтите, что `df.dropna()` удаляет только `NaN`, а не пробелы. Если у вас в столбце пробелы, то такой столбец нужно будет сначала преобразовать к числовому типу данных:

```
df["col_name"] = pd.to_numrtic(df["col_name"], errors="coerce")
```

Comment: А если будут строки с пропусками и столбцы с разным типом данных, как быть тогда?

Comment: @CR7, можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: В моем примере пропуски = NaN , пробелов нет, поэтому думаю можно в отдельный вопрос вынести поиск пробелом в данных?

Comment: @CR7, лучше конечно в отдельный. Но главное - это воспроизводимый пример данных, который поможет понять что вы имеете ввиду. Я ваш вопрос из первого комментария не понял...

Comment: Если бы в одном из столбцов был текстовый тип данных с пробелами, тогда бы не удалось воспользоваться ```df.dropna``` , да и числовому типу ```pd.to_numeric``` тоже не приведешь. А убрать 20% пропусков/NaN/пробелов все равно нужно

Comment: @CR7, предлагаю продолжить нашу дискуссию в новом вопросе с воспроизводимым примером данных и ожидаемым результатом )

Comment: пожалуй , так и поступим