# Выбор столбцов с разным типом данных с пробелами и пропусками Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Есть следующий массив данных:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
6   3   rjhj    8       10
10  2   dsad    8   8   8
4   7   fasd    6       6
    9   fasd    9   5   9
    8   sfd 3       7
            6   2   9
8           9   3   4
6           5   2   2
10  3   fasd    2   10  6
10  10      8   2   6
```

В некоторых местах будут `NaN` , а в некоторых записан пробел. Необходимо оставить только те столбцы, в которых не более 20% пропусков/пробелов/NaN. То есть на выходе нужно получить:

```
Col4    Col6
8   10
8   8
6   6
9   9
3   7
6   9
9   4
5   2
2   6
8   6
```

[Залил файл для проверки](https://dropmefiles.com/bgB0G)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените пробелы на `NaN` и воспользуйтесь [решением из ответа на ваш предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1349724/211923):

```
res = df.replace(["", " "], np.nan).dropna(thresh=int(len(df) * 0.8), axis=1)
```